# Proxy server for a hybrid system in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, networking, proxy

[image]

I have an application developed in C# for desktop which will access MySql Database in an online server. Since it is a shared database the client IP can't access the Database directly so i need to implement a proxy server which can accept the request from the client and after processing the business logic by using the Database it will return the result back to the client. The proxy will be acting as an intermediator. I haven't been able to think of a way to implement the proxy server to handle the request. Leaving the Proxy aside the other things are  in place and running fine. Any other alternative is most welcome!!!!

Comment: You can build a simple web service that accepts SQL (or whatever), executes it against the database and dumps the recordset to your app.

Comment: will it be secure and mysql is shared database so only website IP can access it

Comment: If you'll make it secure, it will be secure.

Comment: thank you for the answers...any example for this type web service will be very much be appreciated

Comment: I don't know any. :-) But you did understand the concept, right?

Comment: yup :) I will have to check for it though..looks like a pretty tough kind of coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be better if your application just makes a HTTP-request to a page on your server, and the page itself executes the query and returns the result as json, xml, csv or whathaveyou? This way you avoid problems with users behind a firewall who can only use port 80, and it's easier for you to filter out malicious queries in your script before they reach the database.

Comment: I will definitely try to test with it. Thanks for the suggestion.